# Getting an array with all positions names from a Joomla template

Tags: php, joomla

I want to get an array with all current template positions names as listed in the respective templateDetails.xml.

I tried:

```
$this->params->get('positions')
```

But it didn't work.

The code will be called or inserted into /templates/mytemplate/index.php file.

I've seen in the module parameters page a select that displays all available positions from all installed templates, maybe it gives a clue on how to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

Recently I edited a post in joomla docs here https://docs.joomla.org/JFactory/getXMLParser. Hardly 1 week back as it was not updated for a long time. You can get template position this way after giving `templateDetails.xml` location.

```
$xmlfile = 'templates/protostar/templateDetails.xml';//Change to your template
$xml = JFactory::getXML( $xmlfile );
//The position array is this `$xml->positions->position` 
foreach ($xml->positions->position as $position) {
  echo $position . "<br />";
}
```